# Will google index a button click inside a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had the following code suggested to me. My question is to ask if Google will index this.

```
<form style="display: inline" action="http://example.com/" method="get">
  <button>Visit Website</button>
</form>
```

What are my other options? It's important for me to retain the button widget look for the link. Previously I used the following but I was told this was not a good idea:

```
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">
   <button disabled="disabled" >ABC</button>
 </a>
```

I think there is another option with the button click event but I am not sure how to code that and if that will index on Google.  I also use jQuery on the web page and have that as an option.

Most important however is that I have been told I must use the "button" widget so the button looks the same as others on the page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a normal `<a href>` link and style it and all the `<button>`s to look the same with CSS:

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
    button, input[type=submit], .btn {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: normal;
        padding: 3px;
        border: 2px outset #000;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px; 
        background: rgb(232,232,232); /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(232,232,232,1) 0%, rgba(229,229,229,1) 44%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(232,232,232,1)), color-stop(44%,rgba(229,229,229,1)), color-stop(71%,rgba(204,204,204,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(216,216,216,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(232,232,232,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 44%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(232,232,232,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 44%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(232,232,232,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 44%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e8e8e8', endColorstr='#d8d8d8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(232,232,232,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 44%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%); /* W3C */
        cursor: default;
    }

    button:hover, input[type=submit]:hover, .btn:hover {
        background: #eee;
    }

    button:active, input[type=submit]:active, .btn:active {
        border: 2px inset;
    }
</style>
<form action="http://www.example.com" method="get">
<button>This is a button</button>
<a class="btn" href="http://www.example.com">This is a link</a>
<input type="submit" value="This is a submit button">
</form>
```

This will make the `<button>`s and links with the class `.btn` look virtually identical.  The only noticeable difference it that the `outline` which elements receive when they have the focus shows up inside of the "real" buttons and around the outside of the links.

Comment: @Marie Just in case you were wondering, I used the [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to create the gradient.  [CSS3Generator.com](http://css3generator.com/) is also handy for creating things like border-radius and other new not-quite-standard things.

Answer (score 2):

It will not index the action of a form tag.  If you are trying to preserve the look you could do something like this with an image of the button:

```
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com" title="visit stackoverflow"><img src="button.jpg" title="button" alt="button" \></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to ask if the google web crawler will crawl (follow) that link.
I really don't know that but i expect it would.
However if it does not you can always use:

```
<a style="display:none;" href="www.stackoverflow.com" />
```

And it will crawl that (at least it did on some of my pages).

Answer (score 0):

Google won't submit the form to index your site.

However, since all you want is to preserve that look, why not just have a link to the rest of your site in your footer or navigation? You could even submit a sitemap to Google. Or just submit the URL  : http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl